tengo que hacer un zip para subir mi pagina en Mercado Shops usando "npm run create-zip" y me tira error
Estoy queriendo customizar mi Mercado Shop y me baje el zip con el html. Una vez que hice los cambios tengo que subir de nuevo un .zip (crearlo a traves de npm porque si no , no lo toma) . Pero cuando hago "npm run create-zip" , me tira un error de que no encuentra el archivo sripts.hbs en ese directorio ( y es cierto, no existe) : Copio el error para que lo vean y me sugieran una solucion :
valelt@MacBook-Air-de-Vale HTMLMercadoShop % npm run create-zip


> @ create-zip /Users/valelt/HTMLMercadoShop
> node ./lib/publish

fs.js:476
  handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
  ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './views/partials/scripts.hbs'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:476:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:377:35)
    at file:///Users/valelt/HTMLMercadoShop/lib/publish.js:5:22
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:152:23)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:166:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: './views/partials/scripts.hbs'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ create-zip: `node ./lib/publish`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ create-zip script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/valelt/.npm/_logs/2024-06-04T14_03_01_607Z-debug.log


valelt@MacBook-Air-de-Vale HTMLMercadoShop % ls ./views/partials/scripts.hbs

ls: ./views/partials/scripts.hbs: No such file or directory

